# Manually setting Xorg options from command-line?

Tags: command-line, bash, xorg

Quick question: how do you set xorg options with a command?

For example, I have an Xorg entry as follows:

```
Section "InputClass"
    Identifier  "Marble Mouse"
    MatchProduct "Logitech USB Trackball"
    ...
    Option "VertScrollDelta" "4"
EndSection
```

and I'd like to change the value of "VertScrollDelta" without restarting my 
computer. Do you know any command-line interface to it? I've looked into xinput, 
but the properties of which does not necessary correspond to xorg options.

Comment: Have you tried gpointing-device-settings?

Answer (score 2):

`xinput` is your best bet. I cannot confirm this as working as I do not have similar hardware, but try running:

`xinput --set-prop --type=int --format=8 "Logitech USB Trackball" "VertScrollDelta" 4`

The --format=8 specifies an 8-bit integer value; using 16 or 32 may work if 8 does not.

You can also use the following to try and troubleshoot this on your own:

`xinput --list` will show you a list of input devices that `xinput` can work with

`xinput --list-props "Logitech USB Trackball"` will show you the current properties for your device

Comment: I already tried `xinput --list-props "Logitech USB Trackball"` before posting this question, but it did not show `VertScrollDelta` or anything like it. Your first command did not work in my case. If I can get a mapping between option names in xorg nad xinput property names, it'd help; but I'm not sure if there is.

Comment: In that case, it would seem that this is a limitation of the X server. Sorry I couldn't be of any assistance.

Answer (score -2):

try to install and use **gsynaptics** to reconfigure your device:

```
  $ sudo apt-get install gsynaptics
```

Comment: It almost has nothing to do with xorg or its setting.